# Finding differences in binary files

Tags: binary

I have two **binary** files that have almost the same content except for the head and tail. Is there a way to extract the chunks A and E?

```
 -----------   -----------   -----------   -----------
|           | |           | |           | |           |
|     A     | |     B     | |     C     | |     D     | BIN FILE #1
|           | |           | |           | |           |
 -----------   -----------   -----------   ----------- 
               -----------   -----------   -----------   -----------
              |           | |           | |           | |           |
  BIN FILE #2 |     B     | |     C     | |     D     | |     E     |
              |           | |           | |           | |           |
               -----------   -----------   -----------   -----------
```

I don't need any particular method to solve this problem. PHP, python or BASH are OK.

Comment: Do you know the size of the chunks? It can really make a difference.

Comment: No, the size of chunks is variable. The only known info is B,C,D chunks are the same in both files.

Comment: I do not think it can be done in bash. But it can be done by a python program that reads files, extracts chunk B from 2nd file and finds its occurrence in first file.